# Mouseover change tr bgcolor not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the page. http://iu91.com/rs/sale/

The right side listing have a `mouseover` & `mouseout` change `<tr>` `bgcolor` function.

It works fine in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, however it doesn't work in IE.

I've tried to debug it in IE using the developer tools and I can see that the value of `bgcolor` has changed however the color is still white.

I think the code is correct. Maybe the problem is in the CSS. Can anyone give me a hand?

I did not use `background:transparent;`

Comment: WHy don't you use **tr:hover** in CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your stylesheet `base.css`

Check this `css Style` in `base.css`

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre,
form, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, table,caption, thead ,tfoot, th, td, embed, object {
    padding:0;
    margin:0; 
    outline:0; 
    /*vertical-align:baseline;*/
    background:transparent;
    font-family:'Microsoft YaHei',Verdana,Arial,STHeiti, Georgia;
    }
```

Remove the tag `td` from this.

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre,
    form, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, table,caption, thead ,tfoot, th, embed, object {
        padding:0;
        margin:0; 
        outline:0; 
        /*vertical-align:baseline;*/
        background:transparent;
        font-family:'Microsoft YaHei',Verdana,Arial,STHeiti, Georgia;
        }
```

Comment: thanks! that is the reason.  However I can not remove the TD from base.CSS directly. Because other elements need this setting.  How to overwrite background:transparent in a div which id is listarea?  Something like #listarea td{background:????}